# Is it possible to use my name (in Greek) to create a Google account?

Tags: gmail, google-account, unicode

My name is Σ…ς Π…ς Χ…λ in Greek, and I would like to use this when creating a Google account. Is there anyway to get Google to use Unicode when creating my account so that my e-mail address will be `Σ…ς.Π…ς.Χ…λ@gmail.com`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time is not possible.

From [A first step toward more global email - Official Gmail Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2014/08/a-first-step-toward-more-global-email.html)

> Starting now, Gmail (and shortly, Calendar) will recognize addresses
>   that contain accented or non-Latin characters. This means Gmail users
>   can send emails to, and receive emails from, people who have these
>   characters in their email addresses. Of course, this is just a first
>   step and there’s still a ways to go. In the future, we want to make it
>   possible for you to use them to create Gmail accounts.

Comment: If Google ever invalidates this answer, it would be great to read about the change.

Answer (score 0):

Signup to gmail has the same conditions as creating a google account.  [This](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33386?hl=en) states that first and last names can be unicode/UTF-8, and according to [this list](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/bylanguage/greekchart.html) that includes the characters you listed.

Gmail *ignores* the dots between your names, so you would signup with Σ…ςΠ…ςΧ…λ@gmail.com, but it would allow you to receive emails addressed to Σ…ς.Π…ς.Χ…λ@gmail.com - but only if nobody else already uses the full gmail address (if they do, you can add numbers to make it unqiue).